# Undefined Variables when Using Mongo Aggregate Function with a $Divide Expression

Tags: mongodb

In the following Mongodb query I'm getting "undefined" in my $divide expression for "correct" and "guessCount".  How do I correct this? My intent is to return a percentage labeled as "accuracy" that is the result of dividing the sum of correct guesses divided by the number of guesses.  This should be pretty clear from the provided code.

```
guessCollection.aggregate( { $group :
                     { _id : "$imageFileName",
                       correct : { $sum : "$correct" },
                       guessCount: {$sum: 1 },
                       accuracy: {$divide: [correct, guessCount]}, //guess and guessCount are undefined
                        } },
                   { $match : {guessCount : { $gte : 50 }, user: user, language: language } } ,
                   { $sort: { guessCount: -1 } }, callback)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$divide` is a `$project` operator, not a `$group` operator, so you need to do this instead:

```js
guessCollection.aggregate( { $group :
    { _id : "$imageFileName",
       correct : { $sum : "$correct" },
       guessCount: {$sum: 1 }
    } },
    { $match : {guessCount : { $gte : 50 }, user: user, language: language } } ,
    { $project : {
        correct: 1,
        guessCount: 1,
        accuracy: {$divide: ['$correct', '$guessCount']}
    }},
    { $sort: { guessCount: -1 } }, callback)
```

Your next problem will likely be that you're referencing the `language` and `user` fields in your `$match` because you're not including those in your `$group` so you'll probably want to move that part to the beginning of your pipeline like this:

```js
guessCollection.aggregate(
    { $match : { user: user, language: language } } ,
    { $group : { 
        _id : "$imageFileName",
        correct : { $sum : "$correct" },
        guessCount: {$sum: 1 }
    } },
    { $match : {guessCount : { $gte : 50 } } } ,
    { $project : {
        correct: 1,
        guessCount: 1,
        accuracy: {$divide: ['$correct', '$guessCount']}
    }},
    { $sort: { guessCount: -1 } }, callback)
```

Comment: you have a $match inside of your $group - probably not what you intended?

Comment: Thanks.  Good answer and clear explanation.  @AsyaKamsky - I just caught that as well.  The first $match needs to go before the $group.  +1 to you both.